# Access violation when releasing DLL

Tags: delphi

I have a function that takes the computer's name, it is in an external DLL. And in my program I call this function, but I can't release the DLL after using the function.

DLL + function

```
function NAMEPC: String;
var lpBuffer : PChar;
    nSize : DWord;
const Buff_Size = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
begin
  nSize := Buff_Size;
  lpBuffer := StrAlloc(Buff_Size);
  GetComputerName(lpBuffer,nSize);
  Result := String(lpBuffer);
  StrDispose(lpBuffer);
end;

exports
 NAMEPC;
```

// ****************************************

Function that calls the DLL

```
function CALLNAMEPC: String;
var Handle: THandle;
    mFDolly: function: String;
begin
 Handle := LoadLibrary(PChar('DLL.dll'));
 try
   mFDolly := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'NAMEPC');

   if Assigned(mFDolly) then
    Result := mFDolly

 else
  Application.MessageBox(PChar('ERROR!'), PChar('Microsoft Windows'), MB_ICONERROR);
 finally
  FreeLibrary(Handle);
 end;
end;
```

// ****************************************

Running the function

```
ShowMessage(CALLNAMEPC);
```

// ****************************************

With the commented line below, it works ok, to release the  Access violation.

```
FreeLibrary(Handle);
```

Comment: Your code is probably broken because you return a heap allocated object (the returned string) that was allocated in the DLL, but is deallocated in the calling exe. Unless you arranged for a shared memory manager this will fail for reasons that should be obvious. However, what is odd is that you even have this code in a DLL. It's hard to think of any programming language that can't call the system API directly.

Comment: For this simple task to and from Delphi, you can use a Shortstring instead of a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal conditions, it is not safe to return a managed `String` across the DLL boundary. You need to ensure the same memory manager that allocates the memory is the same manager to free it, which is not the case in your example.

You need to either:

- change the DLL into a Package (BPL), and then have the Caller use `LoadPackage()` instead of `LoadLibrary()`. Packages don't suffer from this memory issue, but they do suffer from another issue - both Caller and BPL must be compiled in the same compiler version. If you upgrade one to another compiler version, you have to upgrade the other, too. This approach also prevents your DLL from being usable in non-Delphi/CB environments (not that it can right now anyway, because it can't, because it is using Delphi-specific features).
- change both the DLL and Caller to use the RTL's shared memory manager. This is also Delphi/CB-specific.
- rewrite the DLL function to work across different compiler version/vendors.

In the last case, change the function's signature to use a standard calling convention, like `cdecl` or `stdcall`, rather than Delphi's default `register` convention, and to return the allocated `PChar` as-is, requiring the Caller to free it when done using it. Either export another function to free the memory that the Caller can use, eg:

```pascal
function NAMEPC: PChar; stdcall;
var
  nSize : DWord;
const
  Buff_Size = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
begin
  nSize := Buff_Size;
  Result := StrAlloc(Buff_Size);
  if Result <> nil then
    GetComputerName(Result, nSize);
end;
    
procedure FreeNAMEPC(Ptr: PChar); stdcall;
begin
  StrDispose(Ptr);
end;

exports
  NAMEPC,
  FreeNAMEPC;
```

```pascal
function CALLNAMEPC: String;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  p_NAMEPC: function: PChar; stdcall;
  p_FreeNAMEPC: procedure(Ptr: PChar); stdcall;
  P: PChar;
begin
  Result := '';

  Handle := LoadLibrary(PChar('DLL.dll'));
  if Handle = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  try
    p_NAMEPC := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'NAMEPC');
    if p_NAMEPC = nil then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    p_FreeNAMEPC := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'FreeNAMEPC');
    if p_FreeNAMEPC = nil then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    
    P := p_NAMEPC();
    if P = nil then
      raise Exception.Create('ERROR from NAMEPC!');

    try
      Result := P;
    finally
      p_FreeNAMEPC(P);
    end;

  finally
    FreeLibrary(Handle);
  end;
end;
```

Or, by allocating the memory using an OS-provided memory manager which the Caller can use directly, ie `LocalAlloc()`/`LocalFree()` or `CoTaskMemAlloc()`/`CoTaskMemFree()`, eg:

```pascal
function NAMEPC: PChar; stdcall;
var
  nSize : DWord;
const
  Buff_Size = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
begin
  nSize := Buff_Size;
  Result := PChar(LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, nSize * SizeOf(Char)));
  if Result <> nil then
    GetComputerName(Result, nSize);
end;
    
exports
  NAMEPC;
```

```pascal
function CALLNAMEPC: String;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  p_NAMEPC: function: PChar; stdcall;
  P: PChar;
begin
  Result := '';

  Handle := LoadLibrary(PChar('DLL.dll'));
  if Handle = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  try
    p_NAMEPC := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'NAMEPC');
    if p_NAMEPC = nil then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    
    P := p_NAMEPC;
    if P = nil then
      raise Exception.Create('ERROR from NAMEPC!');

    try
      Result := P;
    finally
      LocalFree(P);
    end;

  finally
    FreeLibrary(Handle);
  end;
end;
```

Or, by having the Caller allocate its own buffer, and then pass it in to the DLL to be populated with data, eg:

```pascal
function NAMEPC(Buffer: PChar; nSize: DWord): DWord; stdcall;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  Result := $FFFFFFFF;
  if Buffer = nil then
  begin
    nSize := 0;
    if not GetComputerName(@C, nSize) then
    begin
      if GetLastError = ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW then
        Result := nSize;
    end;
  end else
  begin
    if GetComputerName(Buffer, nSize) then
      Result := nSize;
  end;
end;
    
exports
  NAMEPC;
```

```pascal
function CALLNAMEPC: String;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  p_NAMEPC: function(Buffer: PChar; nSize: Dword): DWord; stdcall;
  Buf: array[0..16] of Char;
  Len: Dword;
begin
  Result := '';

  Handle := LoadLibrary(PChar('DLL.dll'));
  if Handle = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  try
    p_NAMEPC := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'NAMEPC');
    if p_NAMEPC = nil then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    
    Len := p_NAMEPC(@Buf[0], Length(Buf));
    if Len = $FFFFFFFF then
      raise Exception.Create('ERROR from NAMEPC!');

    SetString(Result, Buf, Len);

    { alternatively:

    Len := p_NAMEPC(nil, 0);
    if Len = $FFFFFFFF then
      raise Exception.Create('ERROR from NAMEPC!');

    SetLength(Result, Len);

    Len := p_NAMEPC(PChar(Result), Len);
    if Len = $FFFFFFFF then
      raise Exception.Create('ERROR from NAMEPC!');

    SetLength(Result, Len);
    }

  finally
    FreeLibrary(Handle);
  end;
end;
```